# Django: Prevent Data Repetition

Tags: python, django

This is how my model looks like,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ....
```

& another one

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....
```

I'm trying the filter out those questions which have answer, I tried the simplest way, i.e.

```
result = Question.objects.order_by('-answer')[:10]
```

As it should it's repeating the question in results if they have more than 1 answer which I don't want. I tried distinct() but it's not working.

I just want a question to appear once even if it has multiple answers. How can I prevent the repetition of Questions in results if they have multiple answers? What is the best way of doing it?

Please helpme. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I don't know if this works with all the databases

```
 Question.objects.filter(answer__isnull=False).order_by('-answer').distinct('id')[:10]
```

**UPDATES:**

To achieve what you need, one method is to add a field **last_answer_time** to the **Question** model like this:

```
 class Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_answer_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

and override the save method of the **Answer** model like this

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
        self.question.last_answer_time = timezone.now()
        self.question.save()
        return super(Answer, self).save()
```

This will update the last_answer_time field of question each time an answer is created. Now you can just query it like this:

```
 Question.objects.filter(last_answer_time__isnull=False).order_by('-last_answer_time')
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your entire model, so I am making a few assumptions - like that your primary key is id, but you can try something like this in sqlite:

```
Questions.objects.filter(id__in=Answers.objects.values('question').distinct())
```